# Should [cnn] be a synonym of [convolutional-neural-networks]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

We currently have both [cnn](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnn) and [convolutional-neural-networks](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convolutional-neural-networks).

Should [cnn](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnn) be a synonym of [convolutional-neural-networks](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convolutional-neural-networks)?

Comment: Well, they have the same meaning so I'm in support of this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, tags with the same meaning should indeed be synonyms. The requested synonym is now in place; [cnn](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnn) was also merged into [convolutional-neural-networks](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convolutional-neural-networks) to update the eight existing [cnn](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnn) questions and deduplicate the tags on the two questions that had both tags.

Answer (score 4):

## Yes.

They both mean the same thing, so we should have only one tag. They should be synonymized, because if you type `cnn` the tag [convolutional-neural-networks](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convolutional-neural-networks) does not come up as a suggestion, and vice versa.

Comment: Done - a synonym has been created and [cnn] has been merged into [convolutional-neural-networks].

Comment: @Ben - answer with that, maybe?